# How to create a maintenance hook?

Tags: pimcore

I´m trying to make a hook into the maintenance procedure.

I have tried the following in my `Plugin.php`:

```
<?php

namespace MyPlugin;

class Plugin extends PluginLib\AbstractPlugin implements PluginLib\PluginInterface {
    public function init() {

        // Make an maintenance hook
        \Pimcore::getEventManager()->attach("system.maintenance", array($this, "maintenance"));
    }

    ...

    public function maintenance()
    {
        $logger = new \Pimcore\Log\Log();
        $logger->setComponent("pimcore logger");
        $logger->addWriter(new \Zend_Log_Writer_Stream('/var/www/site/website/var/log/debug.log'));

        $logger->info('Running maintenance ...');
    }

}
```

I don´t see my message in the logs.. but I have the maintenance setuped in cron, I can see the maintenance are running in the logs, but not my message.

Also the plugin is installed and activated.

What I understand from the [Event Manager](https://www.pimcore.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=16854309) this should be the way to do it.  What could I be doing wrong?

Thanks /J

Comment: Seems OK. Are you sure your init() method in your plugin is run? Try putting that log statement into init method.

Comment: Yes, adding log-statement to my init() makes it print to debug.log

Comment: Which Pimcore version do you have?

Comment: `[2016-07-06 13:30:01] core.ERROR: Failed to execute job with id: archiveLogEntries {"origin":"Pimcore\\Model\\Schedule\\Manager\\Procedural->run() on line 105","memory":" 12 MB"} []` this job fails.. but it dosent seem to affect the other jobs.

Comment: Is your isInstalled method returning true?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116648/discussion-between-jimboslice-and-igor-benko).